# Ajax ResponseText is getting true but can't write to div

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

Ajax Code:

```
    jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
    var valueCheck;
    $('#acf-field_5cdc07b87c8f8-field_5cdc08405814f').on( 'change', function () {
         valueSelect = $(this).val();
         if ( parseInt ( valueSelect ) > 0 ) {
        $.ajax( ajaxurl, {
            type: 'POST',
            url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
            data: { action: 'hesaplama', // The name of the WP action
                    value:  valueSelect,       // the dataVAlues
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function ( response ) {     // to develop in case of success
                             if ( response.success ) {
                                  sonucum = response.html;  // Here we get the results of the PHP remote function
                                  $('#xcvb').html( sonucum );
                             }
                             else {
                                  $('#xcvb').html( '<span>Bu #id: ' +  valueSelect + ' ye ait bir içerik bulunamadı.</span>' );
                             }
                        },
            error: function ( errorThrown ) {   // to develop in case of error
                             console.log( errorThrown ); 
                        }, 
        });
         }
    });
});
```

Functions.PHP :

```
function hesaplayici(){
$id    = (int) $_POST['value'];
$sonucum =  the_field('sertifika_aciklamasi', $id);}
```

**Responsetext show on console but can't write to my div ( id: #xcvb ) Any one can help me about this ?**

https://up.uac.ist/images/2019/06/17/Screenshot_2.png
https://up.uac.ist/images/2019/06/17/Screenshot_3.png

Comment: After ajax success can you check in network what response you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have a few things wrong here. This is the proper way to use Ajax with Wordpress.

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: ajax_object.ajax_url,
            data: {
                action: 'hesaplama',
                value: valueSelect
            }, 
            error: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }, 
            success: function (data) {
               
               console.log(data);
               if ( data == '') {
                  $('#xcvb').html( '<span>Bu #id: ' +  valueSelect + ' ye ait bir içerik bulunamadı.</span>' );
               }
               else {
                  $('#xcvb').append( data );
               }

            }
    });
```

You should try echoing your response.

```
function hesaplayici(){

$id = $_POST['value'];

$sonucum =  the_field('sertifika_aciklamasi', $id);

echo $sonucum;

die();

}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_send_hesaplayici', 'hesaplayici' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_hesaplayici', 'hesaplayici' );
```

Comment: Owww Thank you man !

 action: 'hesaplama',  ==> add_action( 'wp_ajax_send_hesaplama', 'hesaplayici' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_hesaplama', 'hesaplayici' );  and i change append to html because its added to div new log.

Answer (score 0):

Please try it like this:

on php side:

```
$return = ['myvarname' => 'your data here'];
echo json_encode($return);
exit();
```

on js side:

```
success: function ( response ) { 
$(#idofyourdiv).html(response.myvarname);
}
```

Comment: Go to network tab and after that pick the .php file that is generating the JSON response. What do you have on the response tab?

Comment: did you manage to fix it? what was the problem? I'm glad i was able to help

Comment: yeah i m fix it with @dubvader answer.